# PL/SQL how to write multiple statement in a single stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to do the following problem,

Write a procedure that decreases the salary by a 10% for all employees who earn
less than the current average salary.
Treat the content of table EMP as “all employees”. Have your procedure print the name and salary of the first
person whose salary is just below the average.

What should be the approach to solve the problem?

Write a procedure that decreases the salary by a 10% for all employees who earn less than the current average salary.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPDATE_EMP IS
BEGIN
UPDATE EMP
SET SAL= SAL-(SAL*0.1) 
WHERE SAL<(SELECT AVG(SAL) FROM EMP);
END;
```

AND THE OTHER ONE :
Have your procedure print the name and salary of the first person whose salary is just below the average.

```
SELECT e.ename
     , e.sal
 from 
    (select ename
            , sal 
      from emp 
      where sal < (select avg(sal)  
                     from emp
                   ) 
     order by sal desc 
     )e  
  where ROWNUM =1;
```

Now I need to connect both.. How could I do that ...

Comment: Please update the question with the code that you have written so far.

Comment: Write a procedure that decreases the salary by a 10% for all employees who earn less than the current average salary.

Comment: @Hoque:Just write a cursor which will fetch the employees whose current salary is less than the current average salary. Inside the loop first put a dbms statement which will print that emp details and the very next statement update the salary of the emp to 10%. I don't know why have you create more than one procedure for this .If you referring to something else please edit your question accordingly

Comment: @GauravSoni I don't have any idea .. I thought I have to write a multiple select statement in a single stored procedure.

Comment: @HoqueMaqsud:No idea :( ,you have specified in your question that you have already written sub -problems ,what are they ?

Comment: @GauravSoni Can you please check the question again. I have edited the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are a bit fuzzy on what a stored procedure is and how it can help you do complicated tasks involving many SQL statements.

You follow these directions on how a construct a stored procedure.

http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Oracle/Oracle-Stored-Procedures/

Stored procedures are wonderful structures that allow you to put multiple SQL statements into one structure, saving out variables for use in the next SQL statement.  So all you have to do is invoke the stored procedure, and all the sql statements are run, and your answer is returned or table modification is committed.

You need something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPDATE_EMP RETURN name, value IS
BEGIN

    UPDATE EMP
    SET SAL= SAL-(SAL*0.1) 
    WHERE SAL<(SELECT AVG(SAL) FROM EMP);

    SELECT e.ename INTO name_to_return, e.sal INTO sal_to_return from 
    (select ename, sal from emp where sal < (select 
     avg(sal)from emp) order by sal desc)e   where ROWNUM =1;

    RETURN name_to_return, sal_to_return;
END;
```

The syntax may be a bit off, when you get it working, post your answer here as a new answer, and check mark it as the answer, and you are *much* more likely to get help like this in the future.

Comment: Yes, I have done that. But how could I merge all of them in a single procedure.

Comment: I think for select statement I need to declare variables.

Comment: how could I handle this "Treat the content of table EMP as “all employees”."

Comment: @HoqueMaqsud:I think `all employees` means all avg sal is on the basis of the whole emp table not on the basis of some group condtion,like sometime we use to have avg on the basis per department .

Answer (score 1):

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DISPLAY_EMP IS
    IS
    CURSOR emp_cur
    IS 
    SELECT ename
          ,sal
    FROM  emp
    WHERE SAL<( SELECT AVG(SAL) FROM EMP)
    ORDER BY sal desc;
    v_emp_row emp_cur%ROWTYPE;

    BEGIN
    --update all the employee having sal less than avg sal

    UPDATE EMP
    SET SAL= SAL-(SAL*0.1) 
    WHERE SAL<(SELECT AVG(SAL) FROM EMP);

    --display all the employee having sal less than avg sal
     OPEN emp_cur ;
      LOOP
      FETCH emp_cur INTO v_emp_row;
      EXIT WHEN emp_cur%NOTFOUND;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EMPLOYEE NAME : '||v_emp_row.ename||' '
                         ||'SALARY : '||v_emp_row.sal);
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE emp_cur;
    END DISPLAY_EMP;

   --call the display_emp proc to display all the emp
    BEGIN
     DISPLAY_EMP ;
    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need one procedure to do the update, and another function or select statement to print the name and salary of the first person whose salary is just below the average.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DISPLAY_EMP IS
    IS
    CURSOR emp_cur
    IS 
    SELECT ename
          ,sal
    FROM  emp
    WHERE SAL<( SELECT AVG(SAL) FROM EMP)
    ORDER BY sal desc;
    v_emp_row emp_cur%ROWTYPE;

```
BEGIN
--update all the employee having sal less than avg sal

UPDATE EMP
SET SAL= SAL-(SAL*0.1) 
WHERE SAL<(SELECT AVG(SAL) FROM EMP);

--display all the employee having sal less than avg sal
 OPEN emp_cur ;
  LOOP
  FETCH emp_cur INTO v_emp_row;
  EXIT WHEN emp_cur%NOTFOUND;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EMPLOYEE NAME : '||v_emp_row.ename||' '
                     ||'SALARY : '||v_emp_row.sal);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE emp_cur;
END DISPLAY_EMP;
```

--call the display_emp proc to display all the emp
    BEGIN
     DISPLAY_EMP ;
    END;